# Erasing a character produces a bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The goal of my small experiment is simple: filter/search the users whose names match the current value typed on input text field. To achieve such functionality, I use `RegExp()`. Everything is fine except when I erase a character; doing so makes the filtration stop.

In the constructor:

```
state = { users: [] }
```

The event:

```
searchUser = e => {
  const target = e.target;

  this.setState(state => {
    const regex = new RegExp(target.value, 'i');
    const filteredUsers = state.users.filter(user => regex.test(user.name));

    return { users: filteredUsers }
  })
}
```

Inside `render()`:

```
<input type='text' onChange={this.searchUser} />
```

Is it because of `setState()` being asynchronous?

The fetching of list of users is done inside `componentDidMount()` using `fetch()` and `async/await`.

Comment: Can you create example in stackblitz?

Comment: Did you check whether the onChange event fires when you expect it to? onChange should fire when the element loses focus. It's not clear from your description whether this is what you expect.

Comment: @dybzon React onChange callback  is effectively "oninput"

Comment: @YuryTarabanko true... disregard my comment. The issue is most likely what Sami described in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are effectively, when typing, just filtering with a narrower and narrower argument. When erasing, your `state.users` has been mutated to only contain the previously filtered users, which looks like it stops working.

To fix this, change

```
const filteredUsers = state.users.filter(user => regex.test(user.name));
```

to something like

```
const filteredUsers = allUsers.filter(user => regex.test(user.name));
```

Comment: So, I should store `state.users` in a variable?

Comment: You should probably have `state.users` and `state.filteredUsers` separately.

Comment: I clearly understand now. I realized that the original state isn't going back to its previous form even without erasing characters. Thanks!